# need to undo an imported calendar file

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I accidentally imported an iCalendar file 2x to my tablet from work.  I now have 2 of every event. How do I undo this without manually deleting them 1 by one. there are years worth of events.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was one by one...a better choice would have been to create a new calendar in google calendar  which could have been deleted in whole.